# When clicking "Buy Now" button, an ajax post should send data to a route "/buy"

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I'm trying to figure out how to extract data from a form with radio buttons when clicking the "buy now" button. I know in react you can grab the values and set state, but I'm trying to use an ajax call which I'm not 100% on how to set it up. I trying follow the axios github page but I'm more confused. I am missing a dependency because that's what my error message said. If anyone could clear up how this is set up that would be great!

This is my error message:

[image: error message]

Here is my App.js where my click function lives:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import eyewearData from "./data/eyewear.json";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import EyewearContent from "./components/EyewearContent";
import Buy from "./components/Buy";
import SelectEyewearPage from "./components/SelectEyewearPage";
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      eyewearData: eyewearData,
      img: {},
      title: "",
      name: "",
      price: "",
      description: "",
      sizes: [],
      purchaseVal: "",
      redirect: false
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      purchaseVal: e.target.value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const purchaseVal = {
      purchaseVal: this.state.purchaseVal
    };

    axios.post("/selecteyewear", 
      { purchaseVal }).then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error.request);
      console.log(error.message);
    });
  };

  handleClick(data) {
    this.state.eyewearData.eyewear.filter( eyewear => {
      console.log(eyewear.id === data.target.getAttribute("data-id") && this.setState({
        img: eyewear.images,
        title: eyewear.brand,
        name: eyewear.name,
        price: eyewear.price,
        description: eyewear.description,
        sizes: eyewear.sizes
      }))
    })
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Header />
                <Route exact path="/" render={() => <EyewearContent 
            eyewearData={this.state.eyewearData} 
            handleClick={this.handleClick} 
            img={this.state.img}
            title={this.state.title} 
            name={this.state.name}
            price={this.state.price}
            description={this.state.description}
            sizes={this.state.sizes}
            handlePurchaseEvent={this.handlePurchaseEvent} />} />
                <Route exact path="/buy" component={Buy} />
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is the file where my form lives:

```
import React from "react";

const EyewearPurchaseBtn = (props) => (
    <div>
        <form className="eyewear-purchase-form" onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
            <h3>Select Size</h3>

                    {
                        props.sizes.map( size => (
                            <div key={size} >
                            <input onChange={props.handleChange} className="radio-btn" type="radio" name="purchaseVal" value={size} />
                            <label className="eyewear-purchase-label">{size}</label><br/>   
                            </div>
                        ))
                    }

                    <button className="buy-now">Buy Now</button>    
                </form>
    </div>
);

export default EyewearPurchaseBtn;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the full path of axios in the import statement

`import axios from 'axios';`

P.S. just reinstall axios via npm/yarn if it is still throwing you error

Comment: Yup, just fixed that in my code. My error is I get it now a 404.

Comment: No problem, you are getting the 404 on which resource file ?

Comment: @StacyAreas You need to pass the full url to axios: `axios.post('/buy',` should be something like `axios.post('http://myapi.com/buy',`

Comment: That make no difference. I still get a 404.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the 404 error that you're getting in your question....it'll help us to identify which resource is it unable to locate

Comment: Then sounds like your backend doesn't support that route.

Comment: I'm not work with a backend. Can I not use axios is I have no backend? Also, add the photo of my error.

Comment: Okay.....so the thing is the address you&#39;ve mentioned for the eyewear is wrong.....like you said....you don&#39;t have a backend.....so I am assuming you are sending the data to an online source. Paste the URL of that source in the axios statement. 

As for your question, if there is transfer of data involved....you should axios.